# How do I resolve the error: "The field 'grant_type_id' doesn't exist. in civicrm_api3()" using Drupal 9.x CiviCRM 5.52.3

Tags: webform-civicrm

Error when clicking "CiviCRM" tab when building a new Webform:-

"CiviCRM_API3_Exception: The field 'grant_type_id' doesn't exist. in civicrm_api3()"

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out to be the CiviGrant extension which is disabled by default.

This used to be a core Component but is now an extension which must be enabled to resolve this error.

To enable the extension, navigate to: "Administer/System Settings/Extensions" and click "Enable" on the "CiviGrant" line.